# Turtles cut links Netlogo

Tags: netlogo

anyone wo can help me with my Netlogo project? 
I build up a network of cities (linked with streets) with some infected cities within. The infected cities are trying to infect the susceptible ones over the streets (links). HERE the problem: How can i tell the healthy city to cut the connection with the infected city?

Grateful for each hint.
Greets, 
Yannick

Answer (score 2):

How about making the infected links change an attribute of the links they have. Like:

```
    links-own [infected-link]
            ask cities with [infected? = "yes"][
            ask my-links [set infected-link = "yes"]]
```

then you can have disease-free cities

```
ask my-links with [infected-link = "yes"] [die]
```

at whatever rate or opportunity you'd like.

Comment: Thanks Andrew, I will try it that way!